# using if...then...else in to check if an object already exists

Tags: python

In the create new critter block I want to check if the critter already exists or not. I have added an if...then ...else structure in it but when I run the program and tries to add a new critter (the one that doesn't already exists), the output is:

> *Enter a name for your new critter: Dog New critter has been created. 
>   the critter is named:  Dog That critter already exists*

It creates the new critter but it also displays the message "That critter already exists". How do I get rid of that message so that it only appears if the critter already exists?

```
class Critter(object):   
    noc = []
    # I have omitted ther rest of the code of the class for simplicity.

# main    
# Create a new critter/object using the class Critter and store it in the list named noc
new_crit = input("Enter a name for your new critter: ")
for i in noc:
    if i.name != new_crit:  # name is a parameter used in the class Critter
        Critter.noc.append(Critter(new_crit))
        print("New critter has been created. the critter is named: ", new_crit)
    else:
        print("That critter already exists")
```

Comment: Please cut this down to a [mcve].

Comment: @jonrsharpe I followed your advice and shortened the code. Please have a look at it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing each already-existing critter in `noc`, and if you have more than one critter *and* the picked name *already* is used, you end up both adding a new critter *and* complaining the name already exists.

Decouple the two tests; first see if the name already exists, and *only when the loop is done* add the new critter:

```
new_crit = input("Enter a name for your new critter: ")
for i in noc:
    if i.name == new_crit:  # name is a parameter used in the class Critter
        print("That critter already exists")
        return

# we can only get here if no such name was found, otherwise the function
# would have exited at the `return`
Critter.noc.append(Critter(new_crit))
print("New critter has been created. the critter is named: ", new_crit)
```

If this is not inside a function, you can use `break` and `for...else` (so attach the `else` block to the `for` statement, **not** the `if` statement):

```
new_crit = input("Enter a name for your new critter: ")
for i in noc:
    if i.name == new_crit:  # name is a parameter used in the class Critter
        print("That critter already exists")
        break
else:
    # we can only get here if no such name was found, otherwise the for 
    # loop would have ended at the `break`
    Critter.noc.append(Critter(new_crit))
    print("New critter has been created. the critter is named: ", new_crit)
```

The `else` block of a `for` loop is only executed if the `for` loop completed all iterations without a `break`. Since `break` is only executed if there is a matching name found, you can safely assume there is no such name and create a new `Critter()` in the `else` block.

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked smoothly

Comment: Both the examples are brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `for i in Critter.noc:`, use `if i.name in Critter.noc` print error, else `Critter.noc.append(Critter(new_crit))`

Comment: That won't work, because `Critter.noc` contains *`Critter` instances*, not names.

Comment: that doesn't work because 'for i' gets elements from the list

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, you are right.

Comment: Oops, wished to write code that was easy for beginners, though resource intensive, as in
`if Critter(new_crit) in Critter.noc:
        print("That critter already exists")
    else:
        Critter.noc.append(Critter(new_crit))
        print("New critter has been created. the critter is named: ", new_crit)`

Comment: But it is not possible without overloading the equality operator, which is not beginner stuff.
`def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == other.name` in the Critter class.